# How to use delegate with lambda expression to sum up the odd number in the array

Tags: c#, .net

suppose I have an array

```
int[] nums = new int[]{2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8}
```

How do I use the delegate with the lambda expression to sum up the odd number in the array? I can do that with a for loop with a condition to check whether the number is odd and sum them up easily. Just wondering if there's any way to make the code shorter with delegate and lambda expression.

Thanks

Comment: `var sum = nums.Where(n => n % 2 == 1).Sum();` like this or were you expecting something else?

Comment: Thanks. Is There any way to achieve it without using linq? I want to use something like func delegate to make the code short.

Comment: @CrazyCode but it is LINQ that *adds* a lot of APIs that make use of func delegates; there *are some* pre-existing non-LINQ APIs that take delegates, but they're much rarer ... you'd typically just loop? `int sum = 0; foreach(int i in nums) if(i % 2 != 0) sum += i;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var nums = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        var sum = nums.Sum(delegate(int i) { return i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : i; });
```

I believe this is what your asking for. Unless you want to create the delegate method outside of the lambda section in which case you could do something like this:

```
        var nums = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        var del = new Func<int,int>((i) => i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : i);
        var sum = nums.Sum(i => del(i));
```

Comment: Not bad. Thanks Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ's `Sum()` and check whether the current number is odd:

```
var oddsSum = nums.Sum(x => x % 2 * x);
```

or more verbose using `Where()` filtering:

```
var oddsSum = nums.Where(x => x % 2 == 1).Sum();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is There any way to achieve it without using linq? I want to use something like func delegate to make the code short.

Comment: How much shorter do you want to get? Isnt that pretty short already?

Comment: @CrazyCode How many characters should it be shorter than this answer?

Comment: `.Sum(n => n % 2 * n)`

Comment: Delegate and linq are two defferent things right? Just wondering if it can be achieved by delegate.

Comment: @CrazyCode  `Delegate and linq are two defferent things right?` Yes you take this linq query `var res = nums.Sum(n => n % 2 * n);` and write it as `var res2 = nums.Sum(delegate (int n) { return n % 2 * n; });` it becomes a delegate :))

Comment: @Adrian At least you could have refered in your answer who created the shortest code, -1